# How to stop and restart a Compute Engine VM that runs a Docker container

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine

I'm running a Docker container on Compute Engine, [using the Container Image VM property](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers).

However, if I stop and restart the VM, my app works but the logs aren't collected any more.

When I run `docker ps` I only see my own Docker image. However, for a new VM that hasn't been stopped I also see a container image called `gcr.io/stackdriver-agents/stackdriver-logging-agent`.

Are there any specific steps I need to take to restore the VM as it was before it was stopped? How can I make logging work again, and are there other differences I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are running a docker container on Compute Engine and when you stop/restart the VM, the logs aren’t being collected anymore. As well as wanting to know how to restore a VM to its previous form and the stackdriver-logging-agent.

As described in this article [1], you can use GCE snapshots to create backups of persistent disks attached to the instance, including boot volumes. This is useful for backing up your data, recreating a disk that might have been lost, or copying a persistent disk. That being said, currently this is the method you can recover deleted disk.

Therefore, unfortunately if there are no snapshots taken already from the VM’s disk(s), the deleted disk volume cannot be recovered, this process is irreversible [2].

In the future, you can set disk ‘auto-delete’ [3] to no when creating an instance, this way disk will remain even if the instance is deleted.

As for the the logging agent image, it’s a container image that streams logs from your VM instances and from selected third-party software packages to Stackdriver Logging. It is a best practice to run the Logging agent on all your VM instances, which can answer your question as to why the logs aren’t appearing anymore. They are simply being recorded by the logging agent and sent to Stackdriver Logging.

For the logs not being recollected you can try this out to reset the service:

Please do the following on your affected Windows instance:

1. Stop the "StackdriverLogging" service. You can do it from command line with "net stop StackdriverLogging"
2. Navigate to the following directory: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Stackdriver\LoggingAgent\Main\pos\winevtlog.pos\worker0"
3. Remove the file “storage.json” located in that directory
4. Restart StackdriverLogging service - execute "net start StackdriverLogging" from command line.

This should reset logging agent state and make logging functional again.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots

[2] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#pdspecs

[3] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create#--disk

Comment: Incidentally, you can do inline links here. Just do `[text][1]` and it will hyperlink to one of your references.